# Convert old pinescript (not sure what version) to v5

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to convert this old study code from some old version of pinescript (maybe v1 or v2) to the current v5 so I can add a few things to it. I've banged around some and made some progress, but the new code doesn't function exactly like the old code. I think there are some default values assumed in the old code that are not assumed in the new. The

OLD CODE:

```
study("Impulse MACD [LazyBear]", shorttitle="IMACD_LB", overlay=false)
lengthMA = input(34)
lengthSignal = input(9)
calc_smma(src, len) =>
    smma=na(smma[1]) ? sma(src, len) : (smma[1] * (len - 1) + src) / len
    smma

calc_zlema(src, length) =>
    ema1=ema(src, length)
    ema2=ema(ema1, length)
    d=ema1-ema2
    ema1+d

src=hlc3
hi=calc_smma(high, lengthMA)
lo=calc_smma(low, lengthMA)
mi=calc_zlema(src, lengthMA) 

md=(mi>hi)? (mi-hi) : (mi<lo) ? (mi - lo) : 0
sb=sma(md, lengthSignal)
sh=md-sb
mdc=src>mi?src>hi?lime:green:src<lo?red:orange
plot(0, color=gray, linewidth=1, title="MidLine")
plot(md, color=mdc, linewidth=2, title="ImpulseMACD", style=histogram)
plot(sh, color=blue, linewidth=2, title="ImpulseHisto", style=histogram)
plot(sb, color=maroon, linewidth=2, title="ImpulseMACDCDSignal")

ebc=input(false, title="Enable bar colors")
barcolor(ebc?mdc:na)
```

MY LATEST WORKING VERSION (BUT STILL MISSING SOMETHING) CODE:

```
//@version=5
indicator("Impulse MACD [HammerGeek - LazyBear]", shorttitle="IMACD_HG-LB", overlay=false)

src = hlc3

lengthMA = input(34)
lengthSignal = input(9)

calc_smma(src, len) =>
    ta.sma(src, lengthMA)

calc_zlema(src, length) =>
    ema1 = ta.ema(src, length)
    ema2 = ta.ema(ema1, length)
    d = ema1 - ema2
    ema1 + d


hi = calc_smma(high, lengthMA)
lo = calc_smma(low, lengthMA)
mi = calc_zlema(src, lengthMA)

md = (mi > hi) ? (mi - hi) : (mi < lo) ? (mi - lo) : 0
sb = ta.sma(md, lengthSignal)
sh = md - sb
mdc = src > mi ? src > hi ? color.lime : color.green : src < lo ? color.red : color.orange
plot(0, color=color.gray, linewidth=1, title="MidLine")
plot(md, color=mdc, linewidth=2, title="ImpulseMACD", style = plot.style_line)
plot(sh, color=color.blue, linewidth=2, title="ImpulseHisto", style = plot.style_area)
plot(sb, color=color.maroon, linewidth=2, title="ImpulseMACDCDSignal")

ebc = input(false, title="Enable bar colors")
barcolor(ebc ? mdc : na)
```

If I put them on the chart on top of each other, you can see the difference.
Old code on top
New code on bottom
same settings and user/input style settings are exactly the same in both yet they display differently.  There must be a calculation in the code I don't know.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrJrp.png)

I've tried converting as much as I know how to v5 and I am not getting any errors. So, as stated before, the only problem I think is in some variable (or something else) that had an assumed value that is not assumed in v5.  But that is a guess.
I'm trying to get a 100% working v5 version as a starting point to make some other minor modifications I'd like to make.

Answer (score 0):

You've change the logic of the function `calc_smma(src, len)` between the two versions, and that's why you're getting different results. Change one of the version to match the other and you should see the same results.

In addition, if you want to visually see the same visual results, you should keep the style of the `plot` function and use the argument `style = plot.style_histogram`.

Comment: Yeah. I purposely change the visuals to something I found personally more useful and less scattered.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
//@version=5
indicator('Impulse MACD [LazyBear]', shorttitle='IMACD_LB', overlay=false)
lengthMA = input(34)
lengthSignal = input(9)

calc_smma(src, len) =>
    smma = 0.0
    sma_1 = ta.sma(src, len)
    smma := na(smma[1]) ? sma_1 : (smma[1] * (len - 1) + src) / len
    smma

calc_zlema(src, length) =>
    ema1 = ta.ema(src, length)
    ema2 = ta.ema(ema1, length)
    d = ema1 - ema2
    ema1 + d

src = hlc3
hi = calc_smma(high, lengthMA)
lo = calc_smma(low, lengthMA)
mi = calc_zlema(src, lengthMA)

md = mi > hi ? mi - hi : mi < lo ? mi - lo : 0
sb = ta.sma(md, lengthSignal)
sh = md - sb
mdc = src > mi ? src > hi ? color.lime : color.green : src < lo ? color.red : color.orange
plot(0, color=color.new(color.gray, 0), linewidth=1, title='MidLine')
plot(md, color=mdc, linewidth=2, title='ImpulseMACD', style=plot.style_histogram)
plot(sh, color=color.new(color.blue, 0), linewidth=2, title='ImpulseHisto', style=plot.style_histogram)
plot(sb, color=color.new(color.maroon, 0), linewidth=2, title='ImpulseMACDCDSignal')

ebc = input(false, title='Enable bar colors')
barcolor(ebc ? mdc : na)
```

Comment: Thank you.  Big help!!!!!!    Do you know if there is a way to set the overbought and oversold lines that I added based on the asset-pair's history?  Manually setting those lines to 0.075 works for smaller assets-pairs, but not for something like BTC.